# Hiding system calls from debugger

Tags: linux, gdb, reverse-engineering

In Eldad Eilam's book titled Reversing, in Chapter 11: Breaking Protections, there is a crackme called Defender. It is written for Windows, and at the beginning of execution user-mode OS components are copied to a random memory address by searching through `ntdll.dll`. After that OS is accessed through this copied code, using kernel mode switch. This way, when debugging, breakpoints placed on any user-mode API would never be hit.

I am wondering whether this can be done on Linux. I have a simple Hello World assembly code:

```
section .data
    msg db      "hello, world!"

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, msg 
    mov     rdx, 13
    syscall
    mov    rax, 60
    mov    rdi, 0
    syscall
```

If I load the corresponding executable in `gdb`, issue `catch syscall write` and run the program, the `write` syscall will be detected. Is it possible to hide the `write` operation from `gdb` in a similar way what is used on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.  The code to implement `ptrace` catching of system calls is in the kernel, not in user space, so there's no way to avoid it.